# Products dissappeared from bundle options, 2.2.6

Tags: magento2.2.6, bundled-product

We discovered a bundle with 8 options showing as out of stock despite products being in stock.  We saved the bundle and it dropped half of the products.

The products are simple products and available in the general catalog.  When trying to add the items to the bundle options we can not find them in product selection from the bundle page.

Bundles have been issue free for the year with no changes made.  Reindexed, flushed cache.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On further inspection it looks like the entire record has been dropped from catalog_product_bundle_option, catalog_product_bundle_option_value and catalog_product_bundle_selection.  I can insert record into catalog_product_bundle_option and catalog_product_bundle_option_value but catalog_product_bundle_selection does not show any products in frontend or backend.

Comment: I know max post vars setting on sever can prevent product saving correctly. Set it to 8000 or something very high. But I'm not 100% this will solve your problem so not put it as answer